# In my SpringBoot project, an FileNotFoundException occred when i change the file directory to src/main/resources

Tags: java, maven

At first, the file was in the project directory:

[image: at first]

And there was no exception and everything went well. But an exception `FileNotFoundException` occured when I change the file directory to `src/main/resources`.[image: Core code]

[image: later]

I was confused, thanks for your help!

Comment: do I understand correctly that before the project was not a maven project before? Could you paste the message of the exception to see what is the path it is trying to look in? 

Can you try running the command line maven "mvn spring-boot:run"  ?

Comment: when you package the project the compiled sources, as well as the resources can be found in the root of your classpath. Therefore you would refer to them not as `src/main/resources` but as `your_resource.file`, or sometimes `classpath:/your_resource.file`

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: vsinfo.properties

Comment: I have tried several times.Although I modified the property successfully, there is no change in the file.This is very strange!

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared after I restart the computer!But a new problem has arisen!Although I modified the property successfully, there is no change in the file.This is very strange!After I modified the properties of the file, I found that the file properties have changed, but the files are  no change !